# Generic type with collection sorted operator

Tags: scala

I´m trying to create an implicit class using generic, here the class

```
object Utils {

  implicit class optionUtils(option: Option[Any]) {
    def sortedList[T]:List[T] = {
      val list:List[T] = option.get.asInstanceOf[List[T]]
      list.sorted[T]
    }
  }
}
```

And here the invocation

```
jsonResponse.get("products").sortedList[String]
```

But seems like sorted is not compiling, and the compiler says.

```
Error:(8, 18) not enough arguments for method sorted: (implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[T])List[T].
Unspecified value parameter ord.
      list.sorted[T]
             ^
```

Any idea how to make it works?.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that `T` is restricted to an order-able type.

```
def sortedList[T: Ordering]:List[T] = { ...
```

Comment: wow brilliant man!, I would never realize that, but now I see that has complete sense, thanks a lot!